# Formatting Raw String Python

Tags: python, string, format, scrape

I have a raw string in Python that is retrieved via an imap library.

It looks like this:

```
Season: Winter 2017-18
Activity: Basketball - Boys JV
*DATE: 02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )
Event type: Game
Home/Host: Clear Lake
Opponent: Webster City
*START TIME: 6:15PM CST* - ( previously 4:30PM CST )
Location: Clear Lake High School, 125 N. 20th Street, Clear Lake, IA
```

What would be the best way to scrap the data that comes after each label (label is `DATE:`) For example `DATE: 02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )` would be set equal to a variable like `Date`, so when `print(date)` is printed, `02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )` would be the output.

I tried the below code, but it printed one character per line. Thanks!

```
for line in message:
     if "DATE:" in line:
          print line
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and a dictionary:

```
import re
s = """
Season: Winter 2017-18
Activity: Basketball - Boys JV
*DATE: 02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )
Event type: Game
Home/Host: Clear Lake
Opponent: Webster City
*START TIME: 6:15PM CST* - ( previously 4:30PM CST )
Location: Clear Lake High School, 125 N. 20th Street, Clear Lake, IA
"""
final_dict = {(a[1:] if a.startswith('*') else a).strip('\r'):b.strip('\r') for a, b in filter(lambda x:len(x)> 1, [re.split('\:\s', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))])}
```

Output:

```
{'Home/Host': 'Clear Lake', 'Season': 'Winter 2017-18', 'START TIME': '6:15PM CST* - ( previously 4:30PM CST )', 'Location': 'Clear Lake High School, 125 N. 20th Street, Clear Lake, IA', 'Activity': 'Basketball - Boys JV', 'DATE': '02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )', 'Event type': 'Game', 'Opponent': 'Webster City'}
```

Comment: It looks like your solution would work, but I need help getting it to run. I get the following errors: 'File "C:/Users/Lewis/PycharmProjects/alertsMessager/main.py", line 47, in process_mailbox
    final_dict = {a[1:] if a.startswith('*') else a: b for a, b in [re.split('\:\s', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]}
  File "C:/Users/Lewis/PycharmProjects/alertsMessager/main.py", line 47, in <dictcomp>
    final_dict = {a[1:] if a.startswith('*') else a: b for a, b in [re.split('\:\s', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack'

Comment: @user284344 are you reading the game log from a .txt file? If so, then that may account for the error. Can you post what output you get if you only run `[re.split('\:\s', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 looks to be extracted from an email since he claimed he got it from an IMAP library, so my guess it's a string. to my knowledge, though colons in regex don't need to be escaped

Comment: @Ajax1234 I got this when I ran [re.split('\:\s', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]   [['        Season', 'Winter 2017-18'], ['        Activity', 'Basketball - Boys JV'], ['        *DATE', '02/13/2018 * - ( previously 02/06/2018 )'], ['        Event type', 'Game'], ['        Home/Host', 'Clear Lake'], ['        Opponent', 'Webster City'], ['        *START TIME', '6:15PM CST* - ( previously 4:30PM CST )'], ['        Location', 'Clear Lake High School, 125 N. 20th Street, Clear Lake, IA'], ['        ']]

Comment: I don't see that line in your code, unless I'm looking the wrong place? @Ajax1234

Comment: strange, how'd that empty string get in there? `filter` should have removed that

Comment: @user284344 please see my recent edit, I added an additional filter. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you @Ajax1234, but I got a syntax error when I ran your latest edit. Thanks

Comment: @user284344 no problem, fixed. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: You are awesome @ajax1234

Comment: How do I get the dictionary that we have made to not have a /r after each entry? It's screwing up what I'm trying to to.@Ajax1234

Comment: @user284344 I added a `str.strip` method to the answer. If that does not work, could you post the dictionary containing `/r`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to split the string to lines. Then iterate over the lines and use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the data, e.g.:

```
import re

for line in message.splitlines():
    match = re.match(r'\*DATE: (.*)', line)
    if match:
        date = match.group(1)
        print date
```

Answer (score 2):

`For line in message` iterates each item in message: in simple terms, message is a string, and its items are characters (ergo it iterates each character).

Split is the simple/naive approach to the problem but will likely work so long as your data doesn't get much more complex:

Use `message.split("\n")` to split the string on newlines and iterate over that. Then, you can use `line.strip().strip("*").split(":", maxsplit=1)` to separate the key from the value. The first `strip()` removes extra whitespace that may remain (such as a potential "\r") and the second removes the extra asterisks. `maxsplit=1` stops at the first colon (which may be a problem if your data has colons as part of the label).

I say key/value because you likely don't really need (or want) to dynamically assign the pairs to actual variables and can probably just store it as a dict and query it as needed.

```
output = dict()
for line in message.split("\n"): ## Split Lines
    key,value = line.strip().split(":",maxsplit=1) ## Remove extra whitespace/* and split at the first colon
    output[key] = value
```

*Edit:* I was under the impression that "date" was just your example, but if that's all you're looking for, then obviously just add the line `if key == "DATE"` and return/print/etc the value.

Comment: That was just an example, but if I can at least get that, I'm sure I can go from there. Thanks

Comment: I just realized I made a pretty silly mistake ^_^;; On the third line that was supposed to just be an assignment, but for some reason I iterated on it. Answer updated.

Comment: I ran yours, but I got this error: TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Sounds like you're in Python2: just supply the args as positional arguments. i.e.- `split(":" , 1)`

Comment: I did that and got this error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack   code looks like this: utput = dict()
        for line in message.split("\n"):  ## Split Lines
            key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)  ## Remove extra whitespace/* and split at the first colon
            output[key] = value
        print(output) @Reid Ballard

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a file named datafile.txt you can try this:

```
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         if line.startswith("*DATE:"):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions works (and I believe is fairly "Pythonic"):

```
lines = message.split("\n") # Split your message into "lines"
sections = [line.split(": ") for line in lines] # Split lines by the "colon space"
message_dict = {section[0].lstrip(' '): section[1] for section in sections} # Dictionary comprehension to put your keys and values into a dict struct. Also removes leading whitespace from your keys.
```